# Does this function belong to $\mathcal{S}( \mathbb{R}) $

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis

Let  $\mathcal{S}( \mathbb{R}) $ be the Schwartz space, that is the space of all infinitely differentiable functions $f$ such that $f$ an all its derivatives are rapidly decreasing in the sense that 
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x|^k | f^{(l)}(x)| < \infty .$$ 
The question is: does 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\cosh(x)}  = \text{sech}(x)\in \mathcal{S}( \mathbb{R}) ? $$
My thoughts are as following: $ \cosh{x} \neq 0$ for  all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ and 
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \text{sech}(x) =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 e^x}{1+ e^{2x}} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x}. $$
Similary
$$ \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \text{sech}(x) =  \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} \frac{2 e^{-x}}{1+ e^{-2x}} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow -\infty} e^{x}. $$
Which shows that $\text{sech}(x) $ decays exponential as $x \rightarrow \pm \infty$. Moreover
$$f'(x) = -\tanh(x) \text{sech}(x)  $$
and $$ \frac{d}{dx} \tanh(x) = \text{sech}^2(x) , $$
which shows that
$$ f^{(l)}(x) = \text{sech}(x) p(\text{sech}(x) , \tanh(x)) ,$$
where $p$ is some polynomial. Thus $f$ is infinitely differentiable. Since 
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x|^k | \text{sech}(x)| < \infty $$ 
we also have
$$ \sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} |x|^k | f^{(l)}(x)| < \infty .$$ 
Hence $f \in \mathcal{S}( \mathbb{R}) $. Is this correct? I have no idea if $f \in \mathcal{S}( \mathbb{R}) $ or not.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, it is correct. I have some issue with

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \text{sech}(x) =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{2 e^x}{1+ e^{2x}} =  \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} e^{-x},$$

since, as written, you would seem to reach the same conclusion for $f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$, since that also has limit $0$ for $x \to \pm\infty$.

Show that $f(x) \sim 2e^{-\lvert x\rvert}$ by considering $\lim\limits_{x \to \pm\infty} f(x)e^{\lvert x\rvert}$.

Near the end, it would IMO be beneficial to explicitly state that the factor

$$p(\operatorname{sech}(x),\tanh(x))$$

in the expression for $f^{(l)}(x)$ is bounded, since $\tanh$ and $\operatorname{sech}$ are both bounded.

Without that, the assertion

$$\sup_{x \in \mathbb{R}} \lvert x\rvert^k \lvert f^{(l)}(x)\rvert < \infty$$

hangs in the void a little.

Comment: Thank you for the answer and for pointing out the issues!